# PHP Function To Detect Expired Webhooks

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, webhooks

I've been using the function below to test for expired webhooks (older than 10 minutes) and it's been working until today.

```
    public function isWebhookExpired($eventTime){

        $status = TRUE;
        $serverTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago');
        $webhookTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
 
        $adjustedEventTime = new DateTime($eventTime, $webhookTimezone);

        $timeOffset = $serverTimezone->getOffset($adjustedEventTime) - 600;

        $currentTime = strtotime("$timeOffset seconds");

        if ($currentTime > strtotime($eventTime)) {
            error_log('An expired webhook detected.');
        }else{
            $status = FALSE;
        }

        return $status;
    }
```

Starting today I've been getting the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2021-02-01T20:42:09.567506804Z) at position 0 (2): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

As far as I can tell the timestamp format has not changed -- 2021-02-01T20:42:09.567506804Z

I did recently update from php 7.2 to 7.4 but the function worked after the update until today.

I'd appreciate any input on how to resolve the error, reformat the timestamp, or a new function that accomplishes the same task.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that this line is the problem

```
  $webhookTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT')
```

The error tells you that the **timezone** does not exist in the constructor and you use that var in your class instantiation.

Php manual says that GMT is deprecated so I would just try to change GMT to

Europe/London
Or another valid timezone from here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Try to replace the old line 5 by:

```
$webhookTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
```

Comment: I made the suggested change and I still get the same error at the old line 5. For what it's worth if I remove one digit from the end of the time stamp I no longer an error. Looking at log files though the length of the timestamp has not changed.

Comment: You mean - if you remove the  __Z__   (for ZULU == UTC) from the timestamp then it works? -- did you look into few week old logs if  the timestamp looks the same?

Comment: No I leave the Z, I remove the digit just before it. Checking logs that's been the timestamp since at least Dec 1, 2020.